# how to drop rows having a specific time in datatime index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetimeindex

How can I remove the whole row from the dataframe where the datetime column is having 07:15 time in the datetime column.

[image]

Comment: In the image the rows marked yellow needs to be removed

Comment: please provide your data as **text**, not image

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your first column is named 'Datetime' and has a `datetime64` dtype, use:

```
import datetime

# Not mandatory if Datetime is already datetime64
# df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])

out = df[df['Datetime'].dt.time != time(7, 15)]
```